# ExtJS: How to pass keystrokes from text field to Grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, keyboard

I have following grid declaration:

```
quickSearchGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: 500,
        collapsible: true,
        .....
```

Then, I have input element above it:

```
<input type="text" id="quickSearch" value="Search" style="height: 25px; width: 100%;" />
```

I want to pass specific keystrokes - Up, Down, PgUp, PgDown etc from input to grid. So that when user has focus in text field, he'll be able to navigate in the grid with keyboard.

What I'm trying is creating my own KeyNav:

```
var nav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', Ext.get('quickSearch'), {
    scope: Ext.get('quickSearch'),
    down: function (e) {
        console.log(e)
        quickSearchGrid.fireEvent('keydown', quickSearchGrid, e)
    }
});
```

Function is being called (it writes to console) but grid does not react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ExtJS 6, it was really easy to simulate navigation with `bufferedRenderer.scrollTo()` method:

Here, I'm creating `KeyNav` but you can rewrite it to pure Javascript/jQuery:

```
quickSearchKeyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', Ext.get('quickSearch'), {
        scope: Ext.get('quickSearch'),
        up: function (e) {
            quickSearchGrid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(
              quickSearchGrid.getStore().indexOf(quickSearchGrid.getSelection()[0]) - 1,
              true);
        },
        pageUp: function (e) {
            var rowsOnScreen = quickSearchGrid.getNavigationModel().getRowsVisible();
            quickSearchGrid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(
              quickSearchGrid.getStore().indexOf(quickSearchGrid.getSelection()[0]) - rowsOnScreen,
              true);
        },
        pageDown: function (e) {
            var rowsOnScreen = quickSearchGrid.getNavigationModel().getRowsVisible();
            quickSearchGrid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(
              quickSearchGrid.getStore().indexOf(quickSearchGrid.getSelection()[0]) + rowsOnScreen,
              true);
        },
        down: function (e) {
            quickSearchGrid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(
              quickSearchGrid.getStore().indexOf(quickSearchGrid.getSelection()[0]) + 1,
              true);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround you could use. Create the text input in extJs instead of declaring it in html:

```
var quickSearch = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    id: 'quickSearch',
    name: 'quickSearch',
    fieldLabel: 'QuickSearch',
    allowBlank: true
});
```

You can then use it for navigation in the grid with arrows by selecting a record with index 1 higher/lower than the one currently selected:

```
var grid = quickSearchGrid;
var view = quickSearchGrid.getView();

var nav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', Ext.getDoc(), {
    down: function(e) {
        var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
        var select = 0; // select first if no record is selected
        if ( selectionModel.hasSelection() ) {
            select = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].index + 1;
        }
        view.select(select);
        quickSearch.focus(); // to get focus back to the input
    },
    up: function(e) {
        var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
        var select = grid.store.totalCount - 1; // select last element if no record is selected
        if ( selectionModel.hasSelection() ) {
            select = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].index - 1;
        }
        view.select(select);
        quickSearch.focus(); // to get focus back to the input
    },
});
```